# Unpack all files in subdirectories and rename them after their original directory

Tags: linux, bash

I've ended up in an odd situation. I have 35 folders. The first is named 1, the second is named 2, and so on. In each of these folders, there are 4 files. '1.png', '2.png', '3.png', '4.png'. In each of these folders, I wish to run "convert *.png -append out.pdf", and rename each 'out.pdf' after its original directory (e.g. 'out1.pdf' from the first folder) and then unpack each pdf from its original folder. Is this possible? I've tried loops, but all that I've tried seem to disagree with the naming system.

Comment: What do you mean by "unpack each pdf from its original folder"?

Comment: Show us your code so far and where exactly it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

for dir in $(seq 1 35)
do
    (
         cd $dir || exit 1
         rm -f out$dir.pdf
         for n in 1 2 3 4
         do
             convert $n.png -append out$dir.pdf  || exit 2
         done
    )
done
```

This script is posix compliant and does not require `bash`, hence the `#!/bin/sh`.

The code between parenthesis runs in a subshell, so the `cd` command only changes the directory until the closing parenthesis.  The next iteration of the loop will begin in the original working directory.

In your example, I think the syntax for `convert` is incorrect.  Convert takes only one input file, and in your original question the `*.png` would pass four input files. Perhaps that's part of your problem.

Comment: The lack of quoting is *not* POSIX compliant (or Bash compliant, either). Try http://shellcheck.net/ to diagnose simple shell antipatterns and syntax errors.

Comment: Worked as soon as I replaced '$n.png' with '*.png'.